# React Native Camera crashing when forcing orientation to landscape

Tags: react-native, camera, react-native-camera

I am using Library `react-native-orientation: ^3.1.3` It crashes when I re-vist the page after going back
The crash states **Start Preview Failed**

```
import Orientation from "react-native-orientation"

  async componentDidMount() {
    Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();  //<--- Forcing orientation of the screen

    await AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkorderId", (err, WorkorderId) => {
      this.setState({
        WorkorderId: WorkorderId,
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @JohhanSantana Yes got it fixed. Please use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker

Comment: When you open camera, call unlockAllOrientations(). Let me know if you get it fixed or not.